# regex matching and get into a python list

Tags: python, regex, list, variables, beautifulsoup

I have the following saved as a string in a variable:

```
window.dataLayer=[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]
```

How do I extract the values of each element? 
Goal would be to have something like this:

```
articleCondition = 'new'

categoryNr = '12345'
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python there are many ways to get value from a string, you can use `regex`, Python `eval` function and even more ways that I may not know.

## Method 1

```
value = 'window.dataLayer=[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]'
value = value.split('=')[1]
data = eval(value)[0]
articleCondition = data['articleCondition']
```

## Method 2

using `regex`

```
import re
re.findall('"articleCondition":"(\w*)"',value)
```

for `regex` you can be more creative to make a generall pattern.

Comment: Depending on your goal, I'd although this would work, I would stay clear of the eval() function!! -- https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the regex version the easiest for me to understand and implement.

Answer (score 2):

You are having a list of dictionary. Use the dictionary key to get the value.

**Ex:**

```
dataLayer=[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]
print(dataLayer[0]["articleCondition"])
print(dataLayer[0]["categoryNr"])
```

**Output:**

```
New
12345
```

Comment: I think the OP has a string like `string = 'window.dataLayer=[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json`. Your string is:

```
>>> s = 'window.dataLayer=[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]'
```

You can get the right hand side of the  `=` with a split:

```
>>> s.split('=')[1]
'[{"articleCondition":"New","categoryNr":"12345","sellerCustomerNr":"88888888","articleStatus":"Open"}]'
```

Then parse it with the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> t = json.loads(s.split('=')[1])
>>> t[0]['articleCondition']
'New'
```

Please note that this works because you have double quotes in the RHS. Single quotes are not allowed in JSON.